# Calculate sum of each form row after cloning

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to calculate the sum of each row after I am dynamically create these by using `clone()` in jQuery.

At the moment it just sums the very first row and not the second/third etc. Below is the div I am cloning. Any help would be highly appreciated. Many Thanks

```html
<div id="itemRow" class="row itemRow">
  <select style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;" id="jobnumbers" asp-for="JobNumber" type="" class="col-md-1 formfield">
    <option selected value="">...Project...</option>
    <option>101</option>
    <option>1223</option>
    <option>0098</option>
  </select>
  <select style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;" id="mode" asp-for="Mode" type="" class="col-md-1 formfield">
    <option selected value="">...Mode...</option>
    <option>Test 1</option>
    <option>Test 2</option>
    <option>Test 3</option>
  </select>
  <select style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;" id="cetegories" asp-for="Mode" type="" class="col-md-1 formfield">
    <option selected value="">...Category...</option>
    <option>Non Project</option>
    <option>Project Related</option>
  </select>
  <select style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;" id="group" asp-for="Group" type="" class="col-md-1 formfield">
    <option selected value="">...Broad Group...</option>
    <option>Project design/set up</option>
    <option>Holiday/Bank Holiday</option>
  </select>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input id="hdtext1" name="hdtext1" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
    <input id="DaysofWeek1" name="DaysofWeek1" for='1' value="" asp-for="Monday" onblur="CalculateEachRowTotal(); CalculateTotalsForWeek();" class="form-control formfield DaysofWeek1" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input id="hdtext1" name="hdtext1" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
    <input id="DaysofWeek2" name="DaysofWeek2" for='1' value="" asp-for="Tuesday" onblur="CalculateEachRowTotal(); CalculateTotalsForWeek();" class="form-control formfield DaysofWeek2" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input id="hdtext1" name="hdtext1" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
    <input id="DaysofWeek3" name="DaysofWeek3" for='1' value="" asp-for="Wednesday" onblur="CalculateEachRowTotal(); CalculateTotalsForWeek();" class="form-control formfield DaysofWeek3" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input id="hdtext1" name="hdtext1" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
    <input id="DaysofWeek4" name="DaysofWeek4" for='1' asp-for="Thursday" onblur="CalculateEachRowTotal(); CalculateTotalsForWeek();" class="form-control formfield DaysofWeek4" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input id="hdtext1" name="hdtext1" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
    <input id="DaysofWeek5" name="DaysofWeek5" for='1' asp-for="Friday" onblur="CalculateEachRowTotal(); CalculateTotalsForWeek();" class="form-control formfield DaysofWeek5" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input id="hdtext1" name="hdtext1" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
    <input id="DaysofWeek6" name="DaysofWeek6" for='1' asp-for="Saturday" onblur="CalculateEachRowTotal(); CalculateTotalsForWeek();" class="form-control formfield DaysofWeek6" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input id="hdtext1" name="hdtext1" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
    <input id="DaysofWeek7" name="DaysofWeek7" for='1' asp-for="Sunday" onblur="CalculateEachRowTotal(); CalculateTotalsForWeek();" class="form-control formfield DaysofWeek7" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 formfield" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Total, new { @class = "form-control formfield rowTotal", @readonly = "readonly", @maxlength = "2" })
  </div>
</div>
```

Js that I current have is, please note I am just trying to find a solution first and will clean up a lot of this code :)

```
$('.itemRow').each(function (i) {
    DaysofWeek1 = $(this).find("input[name='DaysofWeek1']").val() === '' ? 0 : $("#DaysofWeek1").val();
    DaysofWeek2 = $(this).find("input[name='DaysofWeek2']").val() === '' ? 0 : $("#DaysofWeek2").val();
    DaysofWeek3 = $(this).find("input[name='DaysofWeek3']").val() === '' ? 0 : $("#DaysofWeek3").val();
    DaysofWeek4 = $(this).find("input[name='DaysofWeek4']").val() === '' ? 0 : $("#DaysofWeek4").val();
    DaysofWeek5 = $(this).find("input[name='DaysofWeek5']").val() === '' ? 0 : $("#DaysofWeek5").val();
    DaysofWeek6 = $(this).find("input[name='DaysofWeek6']").val() === '' ? 0 : $("#DaysofWeek6").val();
    DaysofWeek7 = $(this).find("input[name='DaysofWeek7']").val() === '' ? 0 : $("#DaysofWeek7").val();

    TotalAmount =
        parseInt(DaysofWeek1) +
        parseInt(DaysofWeek2) +
        parseInt(DaysofWeek3) +
        parseInt(DaysofWeek4) +
        parseInt(DaysofWeek5) +
        parseInt(DaysofWeek6) +
        parseInt(DaysofWeek7);

    if (TotalAmount === 0) {
        TotalAmount = 0;
        $(this).find(".rowTotal").val(TotalAmount);
    }
    else {
        $(this).find(".rowTotal").val(TotalAmount);
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is your JS? Also, as an aside to the question, I'd strongly suggest you DRY up your code by removing the repeated inline styling and using external stylesheets. Also remove the inline event attributes from your HTML and use unobtrusive event handlers. Similarly, don't create your own non-standard HTML attributes, such as `asp-for="xx"` as it can cause UI/JS problems. Use `data` attributes instead

Comment: Thanks, Rory. I have posted Current JS

Comment: By row you mean the div id="itemRow"? As @RoryMcCrossan asked you, we have to see what's being cloned... You can keep the Asp.net tagHelper but you need a common identifier too.

Comment: Do I have to go down the route of assigning each row unique Id's? or is there a simpilar way. Thanks

Comment: yes thats corrent, div id="itemRow" is what is being cloned

Comment: are we allowed to change your HTML code in order to simplify and give more performance to your code?

Comment: yeah you can edit code , thats fine .

Comment: Sthg confusing here! Is the summation presented here is part of your other functions TotalP1(); CalculateEachRowTotal(); CalculateTotalsForWeek();...  ?

Comment: Sorry!, CalculateEachRowTotal() - is for summing each row

Comment: CalculateTotalsForWeek() - is for summing everything

Comment: Sorry you can ignore TotalP1() f0r now :) - I will edit and remove TotalP1();

Comment: I will provide a minimal solution to show you what's not working here... It's up to you to keep those functions or change them ... what counts is that you understand the logic of what's causing the issue. Because it's an example of a detached code

Comment: Which one you want in my example?

Comment: CalculateEachRowTotal()  and CalculateTotalsForWeek() are main once

Comment: i want to sum each row first and than sum everything that has been entered in a seperate textbox?

Comment: I just added the global sum in my updated answer... It's being displayed in a separate div at the top. You can run the snippet to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer treats a part of your code. The code counts the total of Weekdays in the current Row and in the update, the Global Total sum of all days in every row.
And to avoid mentioning those inputs one by one, it's a better to make them share a classname like here `".day"` or a common custom data attribute like `data-filter="day"`.

To handle dynamically added (non-DOm) rows, we always select their parent container.

```
$('.container').on('blur','.day',function(){
```

And later when I pass the current element as Argument in `Sum($(this));`, I again need to explain where is the parent container. 
It's like saying : **I'm a lost clone if you want to count me with my siblings! I need to know where I'm I? Let me find my parents an I'd tell you where my siblings are located! Otherwise you will count my cousins with us... Because we all look the same** :)

```
thisObj.parent().parent().find('input.day').each(function (i) {
```

You can adapt your HTML code to use this and you can keep your other JS functions too. But if they handle cloned elements/sub-elements they better follow the same approach.

```js
var i=0;
  var model = $('.itemRow');
  var frame = $('.container');
  function duplicate(){
  i++;
    var clone=model.clone();
    clone.find('.day,.rowTotal').val('');
    clone.attr("id","itemRow"+i);
    clone.appendTo(frame); 
  }
$('#addRow').on('click',function(){
  duplicate();
});  

function Sum(thisObj){
TotalAmount=0;
thisObj.parent().parent().find('input.day').each(function (i) {    
    TotalAmount+=parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
});

thisObj.parent().parent().find(".rowTotal").val(TotalAmount);

}

function SumAll(){
  total=0;
  $(".container .day").each(function(){
      total+=parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
  });
  $(".allDaysTotal").text(total);  
}

$('.container').on('blur','.day',function(){
Sum($(this));
SumAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <button id="addRow">Add Row</button>
<div class="container">
<div class="allDaysTotal"></div>
<div id="itemRow" class="row itemRow">
  <select style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;" id="jobnumbers" asp-for="JobNumber" type="" class="col-md-1 formfield">
    <option selected value="">...Project...</option>
    <option>101</option>
    <option>1223</option>
    <option>0098</option>
  </select>
  <select style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;" id="mode" asp-for="Mode" type="" class="col-md-1 formfield">
    <option selected value="">...Mode...</option>
    <option>Test 1</option>
    <option>Test 2</option>
    <option>Test 3</option>
  </select>
  <select style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;" id="cetegories" asp-for="Mode" type="" class="col-md-1 formfield">
    <option selected value="">...Category...</option>
    <option>Non Project</option>
    <option>Project Related</option>
  </select>
  <select style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;" id="group" asp-for="Group" type="" class="col-md-1 formfield">
    <option selected value="">...Broad Group...</option>
    <option>Project design/set up</option>
    <option>Holiday/Bank Holiday</option>
  </select>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input id="hdtext1" name="hdtext1" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
    <input id="DaysofWeek1" name="DaysofWeek1" for='1' value="" asp-for="Monday"  class="form-control formfield DaysofWeek1 day" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input id="hdtext1" name="hdtext1" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
    <input id="DaysofWeek2" name="DaysofWeek2" for='1' value="" asp-for="Tuesday"  class="form-control formfield DaysofWeek2 day" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input id="hdtext1" name="hdtext1" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
    <input id="DaysofWeek3" name="DaysofWeek3" for='1' value="" asp-for="Wednesday"  class="form-control formfield DaysofWeek3 day" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input id="hdtext1" name="hdtext1" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
    <input id="DaysofWeek4" name="DaysofWeek4" for='1' asp-for="Thursday"  class="form-control formfield DaysofWeek4 day" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input id="hdtext1" name="hdtext1" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
    <input id="DaysofWeek5" name="DaysofWeek5" for='1' asp-for="Friday"  class="form-control formfield DaysofWeek5 day" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input id="hdtext1" name="hdtext1" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
    <input id="DaysofWeek6" name="DaysofWeek6" for='1' asp-for="Saturday"  class="form-control formfield DaysofWeek6 day" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1" style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input id="hdtext1" name="hdtext1" class="form-control" type="hidden" />
    <input id="DaysofWeek7" name="DaysofWeek7" for='1' asp-for="Sunday"  class="form-control formfield DaysofWeek7 day" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 formfield">
    RowTotal:
    <input value="" class="rowTotal"/>
  </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks Bilel. I will try this soluton and let you know. Much Appreciated :)